# How to achieve concurrency with Kotlin coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have list of carousels and run over each carousel and based on the carousel `query` I  do fetchAssets() and fetchAssets() is Kotlin suspended function but the problem is each function is called when the previous one is finished I want to achieve concurency?

```
 uiScope.launch {
 carousels.mapIndexed { index, carousel ->
when (val assetsResult = assetRepository.fetchAssets(carousel.query)) {
  is Response.Success<List<Asset>> -> {
    if (assetsResult.data.isNotEmpty()) {
      val contentRow = ContentRow(assetsResult.data)
      contentRows.add(contentRow)
      contentRowsmutableData.postValue(contentRows)
    }
  }
  is Response.Failure -> {
  }
}
}
}
```

````
override suspend fun fetchAssets(query: String): Response<List<Asset>> {

  return suspendCoroutine { cont ->doHttp(assetsEndpoint, JsonHttpCall("GET"),
        object : JsonReaderResponseHandler() {
          override fun onSuccess(jsonReader: JsonReader) {
              val apiAsset = ApiAssetList(jsonReader)
              cont.resume(Response.Success(apiAsset.items))
          }

          override fun onError(error: Error) {
            cont.resume(Response.Failure("errorMessage"))
          }
        })
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your suspend function in an `async` block, then wait for all async operations to complete:

```
uiScope.launch {
    val asyncList = carousels.map { carousel ->
        async { assetRepository.fetchAssets(carousel.query) }
    }
    val results = asyncList.awaitAll()
    results.forEach { result ->
        when (result) {
            is Response.Success -> TODO()
            is Response.Failure -> TODO()
        }
    }
}
suspend fun fetchAssets(query: String): Response<List<Asset>>
```

Edit: if you want to update the UI as each completes, you need to change it like this:

```
carousels.forEach { carousel ->
    uiScope.launch {
        val result = fetchAssets(carousel.query)
        when (result) {
            is Response.Success -> {
                if (result.data.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val contentRow = ContentRow(result.data)
                    contentRows.add(contentRow)
                    contentRowsmutableData.postValue(contentRows)
                }
            }
            is Response.Failure -> TODO()
        }
    }
}
```

Check [this](https://medium.com/@elizarov/deadlocks-in-non-hierarchical-csp-e5910d137cc) for concurrency with Coroutines.

Comment: Thanks @Francesc 
I have added how my fetchAsset() looks like and with your solution it means I will have a result when all my requests are completed , yes? I want to start all my requests at the same time but update my livedata as soon as I get response from on of them

Comment: When any `async` coroutine fails in this code, it will propagate all the way to the `uiScope` and cancel its job, which will then cancel all other child jobs of the `uiScope`, breaking the application. You should instead wrap all `async` calls in a `coroutineScope` and handle any exceptions it throws.

Comment: Also, instead of `awaitAll` you may consider adding the result handling code inside the `async`, that way each carousel gets updated as soon as its result is ready. The code also becomes much simpler.

Comment: `uiScope.launch { coroutineScope { carousels.forEach { launch { when (val result = assetRepository.fetchAssets(it.query)) {... } } } } }`

Comment: What the difference between my solution and updated solution ? I do not the difference.

Comment: In my solution we create a coroutine for each element in the list, running in parallel. Yours creates a single coroutine, fetching elements sequentially.

Comment: I see, but what if I have 10 carousels or more how can do limit of coroutines there?
or I should not?

Comment: You could use an actor with a bounded queue so there is a limit on the number of concurrent coroutines.

Comment: @Francesc can you help me to implement it with actors?